# random.sample in Skulpt?

Tags: python, skulpt

Using Skulpt I want to generate a random list of 5 numbers from the range 0 to 50.  This is the code I'm using:

```
import random
print(random.sample(range(50), 5))
```

but it doesn't run.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it didn't :) but it does now:

```
➜  skulpt git:(master) ✗ ./m run rand.py 
[40, 44, 23, 36, 42]
-----
➜  skulpt git:(master) ✗ cat rand.py 
import random
print(random.sample(range(50), 5))
```